# Doctrine & Symfony - No hydratation data from custom query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good afternoon,

I try to get all data with one DQL query in a specific Repository.

The problem is, even if I have Host & Page[] (collection), the query returns null values for this entities.

This is my entities ([EDIT] after question by delboy1978uk):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\WebsiteRepository")
 */
class Website 
{
    /**
     * @var int|null $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $domainName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $domainName;

    /**
     * @var string $language
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var Host $host
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Host", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="host_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $host;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $pages
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Page", mappedBy="website", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $pages;

    /**
     * Website constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pages = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HostRepository")
 */
class Host
{
    /**
     * @var int|null $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $legalName;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     */
    private $phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var int|null $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null $title
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string|null $route
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $route;

    /**
     * @var string|null $template
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * @var Website $website
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Website", inversedBy="pages")
     */
    private $website;
}
```

This is my method to find configuration ([EDIT] after question by delboy1978uk):

```
class WebsiteRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * WebsiteRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param ManagerRegistry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Website::class);
    }

    public function findConfiguration(): array
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT w
             FROM App\Entity\Website w
             JOIN w.host h
             LEFT JOIN w.pages p'
        )->getResult();
     }
}
```

I expect to returns Host & Page[] (collection) from findConfiguration method in WebsiteRepository.

Comment: shouldnt your repository extend a doctrine class?

Comment: I update the post @delboy1978uk

Comment: shouldn't you have @Entity above your class? like `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Del\Repository\UserRepository")` or whatever?

Comment: I have just added this @delboy1978uk

Comment: To clarify are you getting null values for the `Website` entity or the nested `Host` and `Page` entities?

Comment: Doctrine by default only fetches non-collection properties for an entity. The collections on the entity will in those cases be a `PersistentCollection` (wrapper) with a private property named `initialized`/`__isInitialized__` and value `false`, which means, that it wasn't fetched yet. To signal to the query that you want those as well, you at least have to add it to the `SELECT`, i.e. `SELECT w, p [...]`. I'm not certain if setting the one-to-many to `fetch="EAGER"` (read up on eager loading vs lazy loading) there might be additional stuff required ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you for your help.

This is the solution with findConfiguration method in WebsiteRepository for findConfiguration method:

```
SELECT w, h, p
FROM App\Entity\Website w
LEFT JOIN w.host h
LEFT JOIN w.pages p
```